Why the differential form do not reflect almost complex structure?
We know the almost complex structure on a differentiable manifold is defined in terms of tangent bundle. Now we know that the antisymmetric tensor products of degree k of a vector bundle is again a vector bundle. So let us take the antisymmetric tensor products of degree k of the complexified tangent bundle. Now the sections of this  bundle is nothing but the complex valued differential forms of total degree k.
Now I saw a line in the book "differential analysis on complex manifold" by R. O. Wells Jr.(page 32) that the differential form may not reflect the almost complex structure. But I didn't understand the reason of it. can someone please help me?
Thanks in advanced.

I don't know what Wells or you mean by differential forms reflecting the almost complex structure. Do you mean that there should be a unique almost complex structure compatible in some way with the differential forms? Could you make this precise?

The full sentence written by Wells is:

Note that the differential forms of degree $r$ do not reflect the almost complex
structure $J$, whereas its decomposition into subspaces of type $(p, q)$ does.

What this means is that an arbitrary $r$-form $\eta\in\wedge^rT^*M\otimes\mathbb{C}$ does not respect the complex structure on $TM$ in any way. What I mean by that is best illustrated by an example, so let's say $r=1$ and $X\in \Gamma(TM)$. Then can you tell me if $\eta(JX)=i\eta(X)$? The answer is no, you cannot. Play around with this in local coordinates.
Only if we specify the $(p,q)$ degree of the $r$-form (if it is of pure degree! Which may not be the case) do we know how $\eta$ will behave if we let $J$ act on its arguments; it is $i$-linear in its first $p$ arguments, and $i$-anti-linear in its final $q$ arguments. In this case, only if $\eta$ is of type $(1,0)$ or of type $(0,1)$ do you know exactly what $\eta(JX)$ will look like; it will be $i\eta(X)$ or $-i\eta(X)$, respectively.

I find the statement a little odd to mention $(p,q)$-forms, since, as you say, it's the decomposition of $1$-forms into $(1,0)$-forms and $(0,1)$-forms that uniquely determines the almost complex structure. And it's not obvious to me (but perhaps true?) that the decomposition of, say, $2$-forms into $(2,0)$-forms, $(1,1)$-forms, and $(0,2)$-forms uniquely determines the almost complex structure.

It's not about the complex structure being determined by $(p,q)$-forms, as far as I can tell. It's about the way in which differential forms interact with the complex structure.

@QuaereVerum  what I get from your answer is: if η is of type (1,0) or (0,1) then only we know how it acts on elements , that's why the differential form of degree r doesn't reflect the complex structure but it's decomposition does(as in that case at least it's type is specified ).         Thanks bro for the explanation.
